# difficulties resetting tooltip

Tags: loops, tooltip, autohotkey

I was hoping to reset the tooltip with the AHK code below.  While the msgbox is executed, the tool tip is not reset.

```
f9::
Loop
{ 
    MouseGetPos, X, Y 
    PixelGetColor, color, X, Y 
    ToolTip, %color%`n%X%`n%Y%, X+10, Y-150
    sleep 100
}
Exit

Escape::
ToolTip
MsgBox
Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing an empty value to the `Tooltip` command just removes the tooltip. I'm not sure what you mean by reset but If you mean to stop the loop, you can set a flag and check it with a `While` loop.

```
f9::
on := true
While on
{ 
    MouseGetPos, X, Y 
    PixelGetColor, color, X, Y 
    ToolTip, %color%`n%X%`n%Y%, X+10, Y-150
    sleep 100
}
tooltip
Exit

Escape::
on := false
MsgBox
Exit
```